# Ping SLO : No local sessions found to logout

Tags: logout, pingfederate

We are trying to configure SLO for our SP. And getting below error when initiating https://ping.ap.com:9031/sp/startSLO.ping from our PingFederateCancelURL. We have configured open token for our integration and the open token cookie is getting deleted but still the ping side session is not getting destroyed. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

> 2015-10-14 04:01:46,507 tid:0pmOVItDf1iHmKjm-ZVYBWOTvXg ERROR [org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.sp.HandleLogoutRequest] Exception occurred during request processing
>   org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.StatusResponseException: No local sessions found to logout.
>           at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.sp.HandleLogoutRequest.setStatus(HandleLogoutRequest.java:207) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
>           at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.sp.HandleLogoutRequest.doResume(HandleLogoutRequest.java:200) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
>           at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.exeResume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:70) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
>           at org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.resume(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:53) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
>           at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.sp.HandleLogoutRequest.handle(HandleLogoutRequest.java:147) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]
>           at org.sourceid.saml20.profiles.ResumableRequestHandlerBase.doProcess(ResumableRequestHandlerBase.java:58) ~[pf-protocolengine.jar:?]

Comment: Some more info, I have been trying with different PingFederateSLOURLs to make this work and here is how the system behaves:


PingFederateSLOURL https://ping.ap.com:9031/sp/startSLO.ping?PartnerIdpId=PF_DEMO_SAML2
 >Redirect to /idp/startSLO.ping?PartnerSpId=PF_DEMO_SAML2
 >SP SLO SAML Request
 >IdP SLO SAML Response -- "No local sessions found to logout."

PingFederateSLOURL https://ping.ap.com:9031/idp/startSLO.ping?PartnerSpId=PF_DEMO_SAML2
 >/sp/SLO.saml2 -- SAML Logout Request
 >/idp/startSLO.ping?PartnerSpId=PF_DEMO_SAML2-- No SAML Logout response
 >landing page but still able to relogin

Answer (score 0):

We are not using PingFederateSLOURL in our mod_pf.conf. 
Using just PingFederateCancelURL has resolved our issue. After hitting cancel url, we are calling SLO url but not through PingFederateSLOURL.